# Multipart SMS message decode

Tags: c#, sms

I have successful to execute AT command for list all messages in text mode from usb modem. I used;

"AT+CMGF=1"

"AT+CMGL=\"ALL\""

The return is

```
AT+CMGL="ALL"

+CMGL: 1,"REC READ","53030303","","2017/07/10 13:04:37+24"
050003FF0301A66FB93C0FCABFEB72103AEC26CFCB7410F95D9E83DC6FBA625E87C3DF723A285     
CA7BFDB617A7A0C9A97E9F4B4FB3C7781B2EF3AC85D2E9341F43788FC06D1D165D0BC4CA7A7DD
E739A81D76D7C36C76DEA530BEE5A0A4935A943A8B549D022A7F9BD3EC32C8196E977520D1110    
A4A3AA945A9B34815298250A70E243AC3D36E7A59EE2ED345

+CMGL: 2,"REC READ","53030303","","2017/07/10 13:04:37+24"
050003FF030214C6B71CD46C4E750AA8FC6D4EB3CB2067B85DD681444728A8D99C8A1450F91B9
FD781DC75365B017DCBE93A90BBCE662BAA52A60E2442D3E970DDEBD56ECFC7AEB33CDC2E97DD
70F4DB5D768DDFEDD7BC2CB7B3CBF4F9ABDD9E8B1441A85307129DE1EDF65CA480B2CBE179196   
44FCFD37450FE5D9783DCE5B0BC3CA7838ED021C8FC9683D0

+CMGL: 3,"REC READ","53030303","","2017/07/10 13:04:37+24"
050003FF0303CA6C38

+CMGL: 4,"REC READ","740502437424","","2017/07/12 13:08:17+24"
Enjoy 4GB Internet Pack at only 179 Taka (Validity 7 days) To START dial     
*121*3084#. For details visit www.grameenphone.com

+CMGL: 5,"REC READ","740502","","2017/07/12 20:28:21+24"
We are sorry to inform you that your current balance is not sufficient to  
avail the offer. Please recharge and try again.

OK
```

Here 1,2,3 number messages are multipart. I have tried to decode this on a online converter https://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/online-sms-pdu-decoder/
But it is not decoded. So, of course it is not in PDU format. I want to know, what is this format called and how to decode it, any link or else, please...

Comment: ZOMG!  _"AT commands"_ - talk about retro memories of '90s modems :)    I'll get back in my box now

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be the hex representation of the tp_ud (user data) part of a PDU packet. This stuff is explained in [this document](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/123000_123099/123040/14.00.00_60/ts_123040v140000p.pdf) in Section 9.2.3.24. In your example I could identify the so-called User Data Header. For the first part it is "050003FF0301" where the first octet (0x05) represents the length of the User Data Header, second (0x00) tells us about a multipart message, third (0x03) gives us the number of remaining octets, fourth (0xFF) states the max. possible number of parts, fifth (0x03) the number of parts for this message and the sixth (0x01) gives you the number of the current message part. After that the message data follows which can be of the following formats (7-bit, 8-bit, UCS-2 or in compressed format (explained [here](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/101000_101099/101032/07.01.01_60/ts_101032v070101p.pdf#page=13) in Section 5). Unfortunately we cannot see all the other flags set in the pdu packet which probably would tell us what encoding is used.

Comment: Which libraries can help read multi-part messages. I used PduConverter. dll but it's not effective in certain cases.